# Field to display Previous 30 Day Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data1 
    (
    [Market] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [Operator] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,                                                                   
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,   
    [Measure] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [Amount] NUMERIC(36,10)  NOT NULL, 
                --new calculated fields 
    [DailyAvg_30days] NUMERIC(38,6) NULL    DEFAULT 0                                   
    )
```

I've populated all the fields apart from `DailyAvg_30days`.
This field needs to show the total for the preceding 30 days e.g.
1. if `Date` for a particular record is 2nd Dec then it will be the total for the period 3rd Nov - 2nd Dec inclusive.
2. if `Date` for a particular record is 1st Dec then it will be the total for the period 2nd Nov - 1st Dec inclusive.

My attempt to try to find these totals before updating the table is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    a.[Market],
    a.[Operator],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Measure],
    a.[Amount],
    [DailyAvg_30days] = SUM(b.[Amount])
FROM 
    #Data1 a
    INNER JOIN #Data1 b
        ON 
        a.[Market] = b.[Market] AND
        a.[Operator] = b.[Operator] AND
        a.[Measure] = b.[Measure]   AND
        a.[Date] > b.[Date]-30 AND
        a.[Date] <= b.[Date]
GROUP BY
    a.[Market],
    a.[Operator],
    a.[Date],
    a.[Measure],
    a.[Amount]
ORDER BY 1,2,4,3
```

Is this a valid approach or do I need to approach this from a different angle?

---

**EDIT**

There was a flaw in the logic. My colleague Jagoda got the answer first followed by Gordon Linoff who suggested a syntax which I find easier to read:

```
FROM 
    #DataCas a
    INNER JOIN #DataCas b
        ON 
        a.[Market] = b.[Market] AND
        a.[Operator] = b.[Operator] AND
        a.[Measure] = b.[Measure]   AND
        b.[Date]  BETWEEN a.[Date]-29 AND a.[Date]
```

Comment: This is a very valid approach, assuming that market, operator, measure, and date uniquely identify each row.  However, you have shown a `SELECT` query but seem to want to update the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can deal with updating later ....for the timebeing what I need is for this `SELECT` script to return the correct numbers which it currently is not doing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ......ok my colleague has spotted my error; think I'll leave this open for the timebeing just in case anyone else can see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for dates *before* a.date, not after.  So:

```
    a.[Date] >= b.[Date]-30 AND
    a.[Date] <= b.[Date]
```

should be:

```
b.[date] >= a.[date] - 30 and
b.[date] <= a.[date]
```

or, more clearly:

```
b.[date] between a.[date] - 30 and a.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you are using a DATETIME field. So, if you wanted the entire day you would first need to convert the field to a DATE.

```
CONVERT(DATE, a.[Date]) >= CONVERT(DATEADD(d, -30, DATE), b.[Date]) AND
CONVERT(DATE, a.[Date]) <= CONVERT(DATE, b.[Date])
```

Comment: .....I am aware! It is possible to include time within the type `DATETIME` but in my code the time has already been stripped out i.e the time for every date is `00:00:00.00` .... the data type `DATE` is relatively new to the latest version of `SQL-Server`; we still use `DATETIME` throughout our data warehouse. `DATEADD` is irrelevent as it is ok to do something like this `SELECT GETDATE()-30`.

Comment: Good. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to @FergusBown you could use:

```
DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: -1 ....because I want 30days rolling _not 1month_ + why follow FergusBrown's answer as it is incorrect; it is fine in `sql-server` to use calculations like `somedate - 30`